# How can I make a ProxyPass work for all pages without defining a new rule for each page

Tags: node.js, apache2, mod-proxy

I'm very new to setting up apache configs. The docs don't make much sense to me, I have a node app running on a port that functions as a website, but I want to be able to connect to it with my domain. I've been looking around and figured I need to use a ProxyPass to redirect traffic from port 443 (https) to the port the app is running on (I already use apache for other stuff so I didn't want to switch). And it works generally, but is there a way to make only a single ProxyPass rule that will handle all pages (e.g. I go to `https://example.com/` it will use `https://localhost:4450/` and if I go to `https://example.com/example` it will use `https://localhost:4450/example` and for all other pages).

I would think I need a RewriteRule, but I don't really understand how I can get the page (whatever is after the first `/` or none) using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply run apache as a reverse proxy here is an example configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

 SSLEngine On
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/file.pem
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ServerName localhost

 ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:4450/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:4450/

</VirtualHost>
```

and you have to enable the proxy modules like that

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
```